# How to keep app running after closing it in Windows Phone?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7.1

I'm not sure if the title gives enough of an initiative to describe the issue, so here we go.

I'm slightly dissatisfied with the default Alarm app on Windows Phone, so I've decided to make my own (and also as my first project on the Windows Phone development).  However, as I've noticed from other apps available on the marketplace, the alarms don't actually keep running once you close out of the app, while that's not the case with the default one.

Has anybody figured out how to write the code where - even after the app is exited out of - the app would still act like it's running, such as an alarm clock?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot keep your app running after it is closed. This is one of the rules imposed by the OS. However, there are a couple of other OS features that you could use to trigger an alarm of some sort ...

[Background agents allow you to](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh202942%28v=VS.92%29.aspx) run a piece of logic every couple of minutes to check if the alarm is due or not.

You can also send [notifications](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28v=vs.92%29.aspx) to a phone from a server when an application is not running.

Comment: Hmmm. I didn't realize that. That's slightly... inconvenient. I'll go look into the background agents. Am I assuming correctly that I can choose the interval that it checks? Or is that a set thing?

Comment: I think agents run once every 30 mins. You might also look into reminders http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Getting-Started-with-Windows-Phone-Reminders

Comment: Periodic agents run only every 30 mins (I've found this to be closer to 40 minutes)...  Or not at all if the phone is in batter saver mode.

Comment: Hmm... so I guess there's no easy solution to this? Poo.

Comment: Well, that's on purpose--it's to keep only one application running at a time.  when the user wants to switch to another app, the running app is suspended or terminated depending on memory space/allocation.